# Html Form to Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I'm trying to create a simple pizza ordering program. Basically I made a form with various inputs in it and tried to get the info in it into an array but it doesn't work and I dont know what I should do to make it work. I used online script validators which didn't seem to help so now I'm stuck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>PizzaLife</title>
<script>

var smallPrice = 3.50;
var mediumPrice = 5.00;
var largePrice = 9.99;
var totalSmalls = 0;
var totalMediums = 0;
var totalLarges = 0;

function calculateOrder()//calculate the number of smalls, larges and medium pizzas
{
var smallPizza = new Array()
pizza[0] = document.form.smallP.value
pizza[0] = Number (smallPizza[0])
pizza[1] = document.form.smallC.value
pizza[1] = Number (smallPizza[1])
pizza[2] = document.form.small4.value
pizza[2] = Number (smallPizza[2])
pizza[3] = document.form.smallT.value
pizza[3] = Number (smallPizza[3])
pizza[4] = document.form.smallM.value
pizza[4] = Number (smallPizza[4])

var mediumPizza = new Array()
pizza[5] = document.form.mediumP.value
pizza[5] = Number (mediumPizza[5])
pizza[6] = document.form.mediumC.value
pizza[6] = Number (mediumPizza[6])
pizza[7] = document.form.medium4.value
pizza[7] = Number (mediumPizza[7])
pizza[8] = document.form.mediumT.value
pizza[8] = Number (mediumPizza[8])
pizza[9] = document.form.mediumM.value
pizza[9] = Number (mediumPizza[9])

var largePizza = new Array()
pizza[10] = document.form.largeP.value
pizza[10] = Number (largePizza[10])
pizza[11] = document.form.largeC.value
pizza[11] = Number (largePizza[11])
pizza[12] = document.form.large4.value
pizza[12] = Number (largePizza[12])
pizza[13] = document.form.largeT.value
pizza[13] = Number (largePizza[13])
pizza[14] = document.form.largeM.value
pizza[14] = Number (largePizza[14])

totalSmalls = smallPizza[0] + smallPizza[1] + smallPizza[2] + smallPizza[3] + smallPizza[4];
totalMediums = mediumPizza[5] + mediumPizza[6] + mediumPizza[7] + mediumPizza[8] + mediumPizza[9];
totalLarges = largePizza[10] + largePizza[11] + largePizza[12] + largePizza[13] + largePizza[14];

alert ("you have ordered " + totalSmalls + "Small pizas");
}

function resetOrder() //to reset the page and order
{
if (confirm ("Are you sure you want to reset the order?") == true)
{
window.location.reload()
}
}




</script>
<body>
<p><font face = "jokerman" size="10" color="DarkGreen"><b>PizzaLife  NZ</b></font>
<font face="jokerman" size="6" color="DarkGreen"><i>  Online</i></font></p>

<p><font face = "Arial Black" size = "2">Use the arrows to take your pick of our pizzas!</font><br>

<i>note: max per order is 9 pizzas</i></p>

<form name = "form">
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2">
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">Pepperoni Pizza: </font><br>
Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "largeP"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "mediumP"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "smallP"><br>
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">Cheesy Pizza: </font><br>
Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "largeC"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "mediumC"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "smallC"><br>
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">4Meats Pizza: </font><br>
Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "large4"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "medium4"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "small4"><br>
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">TooHot Pizza: </font><br>
Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "largeT"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "mediumT"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "smallT"><br>
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">minceNcheese Pizza: </font><br>
Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "largeM"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "mediumM"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "smallM"><br>
</font>
</form>

<p>
---------------------&lsaquo;<input type = "button" value = "reset" onclick = "resetOrder()"><input type = "button" value = "Get Em!" onclick = "calculateOrder()">&rsaquo;------------------------
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `pizza` is not defined as an array (1 issue I can see)

Comment: Why are you using the undefined variable pizza?.

Comment: You should look up some basic techniques for debugging and not rely on online validators to do the job.  On the most basic level, use console.log() to verify you have the value you expect at critical points in your code.  The use the process of elimination to find the actual line or lines causing the problem.

Comment: @devlincarnate I did try deleting lines to see what the problem was but as you can probably see I'm new to html so I didn't see why it wouldn't work, I see now I got the whole pizza variable messed up, thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempt to use the following code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>PizzaLife</title>
    <script>

    var smallPrice = 3.50;
    var mediumPrice = 5.00;
    var largePrice = 9.99;
    var totalSmalls = 0;
    var totalMediums = 0;
    var totalLarges = 0;

    function calculateOrder()//calculate the number of smalls, larges and medium pizzas
    {
    var pizza = new Array()
    var smallPizza = new Array()
    smallPizza[0] = Number(document.form.smallP.value)
    smallPizza[1] = Number(document.form.smallC.value)
    smallPizza[2] = Number(document.form.small4.value)
    smallPizza[3] = Number(document.form.smallT.value)
    smallPizza[4] = Number(document.form.smallM.value)

    var mediumPizza = new Array()
    mediumPizza[5] = Number(document.form.mediumP.value)
    mediumPizza[6] = Number(document.form.mediumC.value)
    mediumPizza[7] = Number(document.form.medium4.value)
    mediumPizza[8] = Number(document.form.mediumT.value)
    mediumPizza[9] = Number(document.form.mediumM.value)

    var largePizza = new Array()
    largePizza[10] = Number(document.form.largeP.value)
    largePizza[11] = Number(document.form.largeC.value)
    largePizza[12] = Number(document.form.large4.value)
    largePizza[13] = Number(document.form.largeT.value)
    largePizza[14] = Number(document.form.largeM.value)

    totalSmalls = smallPizza[0] + smallPizza[1] + smallPizza[2] + smallPizza[3] + smallPizza[4];
    totalMediums = mediumPizza[5] + mediumPizza[6] + mediumPizza[7] + mediumPizza[8] + mediumPizza[9];
    totalLarges = largePizza[10] + largePizza[11] + largePizza[12] + largePizza[13] + largePizza[14];

    alert ("you have ordered " + totalSmalls + " Small pizzas " + totalMediums + " Mediums and " + totalLarges + " Larges." );
    }

    function resetOrder() //to reset the page and order
    {
    if (confirm ("Are you sure you want to reset the order?") == true)
    {
    window.location.reload()
    }
    }




    </script>
    <body>
    <p><font face = "jokerman" size="10" color="DarkGreen"><b>PizzaLife  NZ</b></font>
    <font face="jokerman" size="6" color="DarkGreen"><i>  Online</i></font></p>

    <p><font face = "Arial Black" size = "2">Use the arrows to take your pick of our pizzas!</font><br>

    <i>note: max per order is 9 pizzas</i></p>

    <form name = "form">
    <font face = "Arial Black" size = "2">
    <font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">Pepperoni Pizza: </font><br>
    Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "largeP"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "mediumP"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "smallP"><br>
    <font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">Cheesy Pizza: </font><br>
    Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "largeC"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "mediumC"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "smallC"><br>
    <font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">4Meats Pizza: </font><br>
    Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "large4"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "medium4"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "small4"><br>
    <font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">TooHot Pizza: </font><br>
    Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "largeT"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "mediumT"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "smallT"><br>
    <font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">minceNcheese Pizza: </font><br>
    Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "largeM"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "mediumM"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "9" name = "smallM"><br>
    </font>
    </form>

    <p>
    ---------------------&lsaquo;<input type = "button" value = "reset" onclick = "resetOrder()"><input type = "button" value = "Get Em!" onclick = "calculateOrder()">&rsaquo;------------------------
    </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Pizza array isn´t used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help I see now what I was doing wrong :D